# Database of All US Counties based on Zip Codes

Tags: database

Does anyone know of a repository that I can access that will list all counties and their associated Zip codes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us
I am not sure how often it is updated, but it seems to be fairly reliable.